# T4 TransformOnBuild, how to ensure dependent assemblies are copied into $(TargetDir)

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019, nuget-package, t4

I am trying to create a NuGet package that deploys some T4 .ttinclude files which in turn rely on a number of referenced assemblies. But I'm having issues in consuming projects when I try to enable

The .ttinclude files have been designed to reference required assemblies using the following syntax:

```
<#@ assembly name="$(TargetDir)WidgetDatabase.dll" #>
```

In my NuGet package's target file, I configure T4ParameterValues so that the $(TargetDir) is passed to the T4 text transformer:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <T4ParameterValues Include="TargetDir">
    <Value>$(TargetDir)</Value>
    <Visible>false</Visible>
  </T4ParameterValues>
</ItemGroup>
```

In the target .csproj, I have the following:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TransformOnBuild>true</TransformOnBuild>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="WidgetDatabase">
    <Version>0.8.1-alpha</Version>
  </PackageReference>
</ItemGroup>
<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\TextTemplating\Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets" />
```

The problem is that the T4 Text Transform occurs before the build, but this means that none of the referenced assemblies are copied into `$(TargetDir)`. How can I force the dependencies to be copied into the `$(TargetDir)` prior to the text transform target running?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886938/cannot-reference-dependency-assemblies-in-t4-template-when-using-transformonbuil) is related, but doesn't satisfactorily resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem and I managed to solve this by referencing the assembly from the NuGet package folder instead of trying to copy it to `$(TargetDir)`.

NuGet 5.0 provides a [GeneratePathProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#generatepathproperty) property that you can add to the `PackageReference`. This will create a MSBuild property that points to the location from which the package will be consumed:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="WidgetDatabase" GeneratePathProperty="true">
    <Version>0.8.1-alpha</Version>
  </PackageReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

This property can then be added to `T4ParameterValues` so it can be consumed from your T4 template:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <T4ParameterValues Include="PkgWidgetDatabase">
    <Value>$(PkgWidgetDatabase)</Value>
    <Visible>false</Visible>
  </T4ParameterValues>
</ItemGroup>
```

```
<#@ assembly name="$(PkgWidgetDatabase)\lib\netstandard2.0\WidgetDatabase.dll" #>
```

The nice thing about this approach is that it works in MSBuild and in Visual Studio design-time.